# LibGDX - Basic physics error? Cannot detect collision between player and ONE side of a platform (tile)

Tags: android, libgdx, 2d, collision, detection

Couldn't find any useful tutorials online so I tried to freestyle an algorithm for this collision.

Basically, I've modelled the **Player** (main character) and **Platform** (a tile that **Player** can collide with) as rectangles for the sake of collision detection. In my code, playerRect is the rectangle representing the player and getRect() is the rectangle representing the Platform.

As it stands my Player only moves from left to right, so he can only collide with 3 of the Platform's sides (left, up and bottom). I have managed to detect collision on the top and bottom part of the platform, however for some reason I can't detect collision on the left side.

Would be highly appreciated if someone can have a look at my code and possibly find where I'm going wrong.

```
public class Platform extends GameObject {
...
public void update() {
    // Rectangle of player
    playerRect = player.getRect();
    //A boolean that checks whether or not player's rectangle 
    //and platform's rectangle overlap
    isOverlapping = playerRect.overlaps(getRect());

    if (isOverlapping) {

        // If the player hits the bottom part of the platform, 
        // have gravity pull him down
        if ((playerRect.getX() > getRect().getX() && 
             playerRect.getX() < getRect().getX() +   
             getRect().getWidth()) && 
             playerRect.getY() > getRect().getY()); {

                player.setySpeed(player.getGravity());
                // If the player is on a platform or on the ground, 
                // allow him to jump
                if (playerOnPlatform() || player.onGround()) {
                    player.setAllow("true", "jump");
                } else {
                    player.setAllow("false", "jump");
                }
            }

        // If the player is on the top part of the platform, 
        // set his ySpeed to 0 so he remains on the platform rather 
        // than fall due to gravity
        if ((playerRect.getX() > getRect().getX() && 
             playerRect.getX() < getRect().getX() + 
             getRect().getWidth()) && 
             playerRect.getY() < getRect().getY()) {

            player.setySpeed(0);
            // If the player is on a platform or on the ground, allow him to jump
            if (playerOnPlatform() || player.onGround()) {
                player.setAllow("true", "jump");
            } else {
                player.setAllow("false", "jump");
            }

           // If the player hits the side of the platform, 
           // set his xSpeed to 0 so that he does not go through the platform
            if(playerRect.getX() > getRect().getX() && 
              (playerRect.getY() > getRect().getY() && 
               playerRect.getY() < getRect().getY() + 
               getRect().getHeight())) {
                player.setySpeed(20);
            }
        }
...
}
```

Thanks in advance for any input

Answer (score 0):

not if your code has a bug when assessing if, for desired results or simply you say it 0 and you write set a 20 `player.setySpeed(20);`.perhaps not well understood at this time :) but should not be setx ... (0), no setY

```
// If the player hits the side of the platform, 
           // set his xSpeed to 0 so that he does not go through the platform
            if(playerRect.getX() > getRect().getX() && 
              (playerRect.getY() > getRect().getY() && 
               playerRect.getY() < getRect().getY() + 
               getRect().getHeight())) {
                player.setySpeed(20);
            }
```

.
On the other hand if this is correct, the inside, not the outside could
I have not test it, you look just above

```
// If the player is on the top part of the platform, 
        // set his ySpeed to 0 so he remains on the platform rather 
        // than fall due to gravity
        if ((playerRect.getX() > getRect().getX() && 
             playerRect.getX() < getRect().getX() + 
             getRect().getWidth()) && 
             playerRect.getY() < getRect().getY()) {

            player.setySpeed(0);
            // If the player is on a platform or on the ground, allow him to jump
            if (playerOnPlatform() || player.onGround()) {
                player.setAllow("true", "jump");
            } else {
                player.setAllow("false", "jump");
            }

           // If the player hits the side of the platform, 
           // set his xSpeed to 0 so that he does not go through the platform
            if(playerRect.getX() > getRect().getX() && 
              (playerRect.getY() > getRect().getY() && 
               playerRect.getY() < getRect().getY() + 
               getRect().getHeight())) {
                player.setySpeed(20);
            }
        }
```

You can use a log, have if this condition is met sometime

```
   // If the player hits the side of the platform, 
           // set his xSpeed to 0 so that he does not go through the platform
            if(playerRect.getX() > getRect().getX() && 
              (playerRect.getY() > getRect().getY() && 
               playerRect.getY() < getRect().getY() + 
               getRect().getHeight())) {
                player.setySpeed(20);

Gdx.app.log("inside", "test");

            }
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. For some reason in my actual code I have player.setxSpeed(0) but on the post its setySpeed(20). xSpeed doesnt change when player hits side of the platform though from what I can see (even though i set it to 0)